# vertical margin massacre in HTML emails

Tags: css, html-email

I know HTML email rendering is a vale of tears, but this is too weird.

I'm trying to get a consistent vertical spacing between my elements.   I have `<hr>` elements I'm using as dividers, and I'm trying to apply top/bottom margins to them.  However, even though I'm applying these margins inline, the css is being mangled when I inspect it in my gmail client.

For example,

**Sent as:**

```
<hr style='margin:20px 0 2px 0;' />
```

**Recieved as:**

```
<hr style='margin:2 0px 0 2px 0;' />
```

*What??...*

**Sent as:**

```
<hr style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:2px;" />
```

**Recieved as:**

```
<hr style="margin-bottom:2px;" />
```

*Come on...*

I thought that in-line styles would be safe, and that even if rendering was failing, at least the actual CSS wouldn't be mangled.  What am I dealing with here?

(I'm sending these out with standard PHP mail() functions out of a WordPress site)

Comment: "Received as" means the source code gets rewritten, or it gets rendered that way?

Comment: @Pekka- It's getting re-written!

Comment: What happens if you add a space behind the colon? What if you put the hr in a div container and add the styles to that container instead of the hr. So <div style="..."><hr /></div>.

Comment: Also, which mail client are you using, please?

Answer (score 1):

Different clients handle the margin property different. Some completely ignore it. The most common way to get even vertical spaces is by using a table layout for the entire e-mail and use an empty row of table cells and set a height to them to create the spaces. Place your hr's in the tablecells without adding margins to them.

An alternative way to this is to insert you hr's as an image and setting a height to them.

I would go with the first method, because this is tried and tested among most of the popular clients. The alternative is worth trying if you're not comfortable with using tables to set up a layout.

It's never a good idea to use shorthand properties in html e-mails, because some clients don't support shorthand properties.